# Laptop buying guide

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, windows, office

I want to buy a 4th or 5th generation laptop for casual tasks like typing office and coding, but the laptop I want should be very durable and work for a long time in harsh places like mountains, gyms and workshops .
What brand do you recommend?
I doubt between Dell and MSI

Comment: buying guide: laptops are junk don't by   :)

Comment: kidding aside, look for *toughbook* or *ruggedized*, I know Dell makes some and they are better than office grade laptops

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what a 4th/5th gen laptop means, but I will assume a laptop from the era of Ryzen 4000/5000.

Since you are going to places a normal laptop may have issues, I reccomend the Panasonic Toughbook. If you don't like the toughness of it though, I would reccomend getting a repairable laptop like the Framework